# Shorthand if doesn't work properly on php

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have a very simple problem. So simple, that I don't know where's the problem.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    echo "<div id='field".$i."' ". $i > 5 ? "style='display:none'" : "" . ">Answer ".$i.": </div>\n";
}
```

Which I would expect the HTML result will be:

```
<div id='field1' >Answer 1</div>
<div id='field2' >Answer 2</div>
<div id='field3' >Answer 3</div>
<div id='field4' >Answer 4</div>
<div id='field5' >Answer 5</div>
<div id='field6' display="none">Answer 6</div>
<div id='field7' display="none">Answer 7</div>
<div id='field8' display="none">Answer 8</div>
<div id='field9' display="none">Answer 9</div>
<div id='field10' display="none">Answer 10</div>
```

But I got this result instead:

```
>Answer 1</div>
>Answer 2</div>
>Answer 3</div>
>Answer 4</div>
>Answer 5</div>
>Answer 6</div>
>Answer 7</div>
>Answer 8</div>
>Answer 9</div>
>Answer 10</div>
```

If I erase the shorthand if, everything is working properly. It's not that I can't use normal if for this matter, but I'm just curious, what I did wrong in this case?

UPDATE:

After getting the answer that I should surround my shorthand if in parentheses, my working code is:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    echo "<div id='field".$i."' ". ($i > 5 ? "style='display:none'" : "") . ">Answer ".$i.": </div>\n";
}
```

Thank you!

Another UPDATE:

Yeah, I notice the $10 mistake. It was the place of a variable, but when I copy paste the code here and I change it into 10 to simplify things up, I guess I forgot to remove the $.

Comment: You should add parentheses for clarity. For you, others and the compiler.

Comment: ya. I've just get the answer from R. Bazell. I'll edit my question to reflect the answer.

Comment: in for loop `$10` is not right variable, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is an issue in the order of evaluation.  To resolve it, you can parenthesize your short-hand if expression, like so:

```
echo "<div id='field".$i."' ". ($i > 5 ? "style='display:none'" : "" . ">Answer ".$i." : </div>\n");
```

Comment: oh ic! this is it! I don't know that I need to give parenthesis for the shorthand if expression. Thank you very much for the quick answer! I will accept this answer as the correct answer in 8 minutes!

Comment: Well you don't always need to parenthesize short-hand expressions, only in cases when there can be some problem in the evaluation order.  Of course you can always do so just to be safe, and it helps make things clearer.

Comment: @asprin you should make your comment as an answer too. thanks btw!

Comment: lol..We already have an answer. I was in the process of creating the demo before posting it, but when I came back it was already answered. So I put it as a comment here :)

Comment: @R.Barzell ya, I'm kinda new in php and in ternary evaluation, so I don't know that I actually **allowed** to close the ternary expression in parentheses. I will always close my ternary expression in parentheses from now on. Thank you! :)

Comment: @asprin I would suggest posting the answer, then editing it to include things like working examples. Otherwise you just end up wasting your own time :(

Comment: @Fluffeh That wouldn't help much either. Might attract downvotes for having very less information at the start. People here are lightening fast. If you can't get your answer within 1 minute, the other person beats you :(

Comment: I find that I get quite a bit of rep from really well written answers weeks or months down the track - but I know you are a good programmer. Don't be scared to post a *less than utterly perfect* answer and then touch it up to meet your strict standard. You are good enough, trust me.

Comment: @asprin hahaha don't worry about it. you're awesome. thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

I am a fan of ternary operators, but making them readable (at least to me) is the validation check I use. If I can't see or make them do what I want, I split it up into a few lines. Anyone looking at the code after I have it will probably be thanking me under their breath.

```
<?php

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
    {
    echo "<div id='field".$i."' ";
    echo ($i > 5) ? "style='display:none'" : "";
    echo ">Answer ".$i.": </div>\n";
    }

?>
```

The fact you are spending this much time on some code that is a simple output of HTML probably means you are making it too complicated.

More lines of readable code is *BETTER* than less lines of nonsense that no-one can understand or modify.

Comment: well, I'm a new guy on php and ternary operator, so I think I'll just mash them up and see whether I'm doing it right or not. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: Where I am coming from is, if you can't look at the code in six months time and understand what it is doing straight away, it is being "too tricky" and you will find that you spend too long trying to work out what it is doing rather than spending that same time making the changes you need.

Comment: of course. the problem is, I can't look at this code like I look this code 6 months later. so some optimization and code compacting looks like make sense today, but I don't know which one will looks like alien language 6 months later. I put many comments in here and there, though. I hope it helps to remind me what those are. lol. thanks.

Comment: @ChenLiYong If you are getting confused reading it *while* you are *writing* it, chances are you will have no idea what you wrote later on. If it isn't clear as a bell now, I would wager you will struggle to read it later. Just some advice mate. Hope that when you modify it, it looks like it was written in crayon :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this: **[LIVE DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EFWvcA)**

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    echo "<div id='field".$i."'".($i > 5 ? " style='display:none' ": " ").">Answer ".$i.": </div><br>";
}
```

More info on: [PHP Shorthand If/Else Using Ternary Operators](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

Comment: yeah, this is another way to put it without messing with the parenthesis. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in for loop `$10` is not variable use simply use only `10` constant and also html manipulation issue
Try this code,

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
    echo $i <= 5 ? "<div id=\"field{$i}\" style=\"display:none\">Answer {$i}: </div>\n" : "<div id=\"field{$i}\">Answer {$i}: </div>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Actually I have a variable in the 10 place, which has value of 10. So I think in order to simplify things up, I'll just change it to plain 10. But then I think I forgot to remove the $ haha. Thanks for the correction. And thanks for the idea of {$i}. :)